# Drawbacks of Spark Streaming in Comparison With Real Streaming Computing Systems

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-spark, apache-storm

Some say that spark streaming, even though it can handle streams in the form of micro-batches, it is still not quite a streaming computing system like storm. So what are the limiting factors of this micro-batch computing ideology? What makes it less than a real computing system? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Spark Streaming paper [here](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2012/EECS-2012-259.pdf). It compares record-at-a-time and batch streaming. Since it's a paper on Spark, it's more biased towards Spark's approach of batch streaming. Also, the paper is 2 years old and a lot of things happened in that time frame. Here is another [ppt](http://www.slideshare.net/ptgoetz/apache-storm-vs-spark-streaming) to get started.